# WPF DataGrid CanUserAddRows into ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

On a Datagrid I have CanUserAddRows set to be true, however, when I do add a row via the grid is there an event that can be fired so I can see that the ObservableCollection is actually being added?

*I say this logic as the infragistics library fires an event when a user adds a row from the grid*

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, do you use infragistics or the MS one?

Comment: I have used Infragistics in WinForms, but in WPF I am checking to see if the MS Grid is as good as the WinGrid in Infragistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the DataGrid.LoadingRow Event

Or you could actually handle the ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged/PropertyChanged

Comment: Thanks, will this event be added to the view though and not the ViewModel? I want to try to add to the collection via he ViewModel, if this cannot be done, I will be happy to do via the view. Thanks

Comment: The LoaingRow event is exposed by the DataGrid, so the View. Do you mean to add a row in UI and see if the underlying collection bound to the DataGrid.ItemSource is updated? Sorry, I haven't tried this case. AFAIK, the LoaingRow event fires when a DataGridRow is added, it works in virtualisation mode too. I think you could simply give it go and see if it meets your need. Cheers.